# How to add LEDs to a microcontroller's GPIO pins, without affecting the normal pin behaviour?

Tags: microcontroller, led, adc, gpio

For educational purposes, I have to design a simple [ATtiny24](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiLr-_9rqT0AhVshf0HHd3EBWkQFnoECAwQAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fww1.microchip.com%2Fdownloads%2Fen%2Fdevicedoc%2FAtmel-7701_Automotive-Microcontrollers-ATtiny24-44-84_Datasheet.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0PwpygKcSZyK6W6jDlLfkn) based development board and add some LEDs to its IO ports for better demonstration of digital inputs or outputs. Despite being educational, I don't want to ignore the  MCU's capabilities and limit them just by adding some LEDs. Despite looking very easy, I think it is going to be a little troublesome in some cases like ADC.

The first thing that comes to mind is just a resistor in front of an LED, and the second one, a BJT as low side switch. I'm not sure how it will affect the ADC.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ft28ka.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**What are the concerns?**

- The MCU should be able to work at maximum speed (20MHz) and 3.3~5V supply (if possible, according to frequency-power supply limitations indicated in datasheet.)
- The MCU should be fine to be programmed with various programmers ([Arduino-as-ISP](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main.ArduinoISP) or USBasp) without the need to slow down the clock or other things that students may not be familiar with.
- The MCU has an ADC with differential inputs and programmable gain up to 20x. I think the simple methods would affect this but I'm not sure. Using 20x gain with differential inputs may seem out of the book for a student but as said earlier, the board should not be limited. Of course, an error of few millivolts are tolerable and the ADC itself is not that precise either.

LED's are 0805 red SMD chips with `1.8V Vf` and `5~10mA If`. The brightness is not a concern.

Comment: If I had many Leds for controlling Inputs and Outputs ... I should use 8 CMOS buffers. It would not disturb pins ...

Comment: Something as this (sink or source , 4 to 8 mA) SN74AHC244Q OCTAL BUFFER/DRIVER WITH 3-STATE OUTPUTS. Input current : max 4uA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a any suitable logic chip to buffer the signals to LEDs. For compatibility with the voltage range, CMOS type should be used. It does not matter if it is a buffer or inverter or AND gate etc.

Answer (score 1):

As an interesting example, you could look at the schematics of [Cytron's "Maker Uno"](https://cdn.cytron.io/makeruno/MAKER-UNO.pdf) which has a LED indicator on every accessible GPIO pin.

For each GPIO pin they use a MOSFET to drive a LED with a 10K resistor. The MOSFET adds negligible load to the GPIO and the 10K resistor means the LEDs don't put much load on the on-board regulator.

[image: portion of Cytron Maker-Uno schematic]

[image: portion of Cytron Maker-Uno PCB]

(On this Maker Uno *X* - looks like there is also a 3M3 pulldown on the gates?)

They weren't deterred by the number of components needed to do this using individual discrete MOSFET packages but I guess it would also be worth looking at ways of buffering these IO lines using a solution that involves fewer packages.